# DrawerLayout locale does not change

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, locale, multilingual

I am making a multi language application.

On click of a button I am restating the app via this code :

```
public void triggerRebirth(Context context) {
        Utility.setRestart(context,true);
        homeActivity.stopMediaPlayers();
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
        ComponentName componentName = intent.getComponent();
        Intent mainIntent = Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(componentName);
        context.startActivity(mainIntent);
        Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
    }
```

All the textviews are changing but the textviews in the drawer layout I have in the code does not change. On killing the app and starting it again, the values come perfect. Why is this issue?

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Added the solution. please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is very simple(and silly also we can say) to it.

All you need to do is `setText()` via code to all textview then it will pick the correct string value from correct locale language.